# Are subviews into a UIView released when the parent ones is released?

Tags: ios, memory-management, ios4, pdf-generation

I'm working on a PDF app running iOS4.3. I trying to put in a horizontal UIScrollView all the PDF pages and when it's needed drawLayer:inContext: it's called.

My doubt is about realeasing the main UIScrollView. I check it with Instruments and memory don't free as much as it had grown. I have to go one by one releasing de UIView that contains the PDF?

I always release CGPage and CGDocument after drawing. I also get memory warnings when zooming.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a `UIView` owns its subviews so it releases them when `dealloc` is called on it. This does not necessarily call `dealloc` on the subviews, for example, if they are retained elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try not to retain objects or use some autorelease when allocation and check it.